# Connect BLE device using .net core

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to develop a window-based application that runs on Windows 10 OS using .NET core or .NET 5. I am not sure which nuget package supports connecting to the BLE devices.

Comment: UWP API has support for BLE. I'm not aware of any support in .NET 5, but maybe they added it. Questions asking for recommendations for third-party libraries are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: As suggested above you can use UWP (actually WinRT) API. Or you can use third-party libs such as 32feet or Bluetooth Frameworrk.

Comment: If I want to use the UWP API(to access BLE support APIs) in the .Net core 3.1, is it possible to utilize it?